# Calling a css rule from javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Hi all I was wondering if it is possible through javascript to turn a .png that is accessed through css into a clickable link by call that css rule.

```
.calendar {
    background: transparent url("../cal_icon.png") no-repeat 94px 3px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

This is my css rule that I would like to make my cal_icon.png clickable.
Is this possible?
Please forgive my ignorance in this matter.

Comment: You can only make the whole `.calendar` element clickable. The background image cannot be accessed or processed somehow through JavaScript.

Comment: css is just to define styles. It does not make anything clickable. you can use javascript to attach a click event handler on the element that has the class calendar attached to it or wrap the element in a clickable element though

Comment: Thanks for the replays would you guys know any good resources on how to wrap it in an element  or make the whole .calendar element clickable?

Comment: Using `javascript` or just a link ?

Comment: I would like to know a link for reference but if it is easy to understand the javascript then the JS would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, you need to add click handler to the element, and css is just for styling

you can take a look at this fiddle, which uses jQuery (onLoad) http://jsfiddle.net/tq92z/

```
$('.calendar').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color','red');
})
```

there is a css expressions for IE, maybe something else for other browsers (but i can't remember anything now)

http://www.richnetapps.com/using_javascript_expressions_in_css/

but it's not a common practice to do dom manipulations with css